# Kubernetes ingress controller cannot find TLS certificate secret

Tags: kubernetes, ssl, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks, nginx-ingress

I'm actually trying for a couple of days to setup TLS on my ingress controller.
My Kubernetes cluster is hosted on Azure (AKS).

When I check the Ingress controller logs, I get this :

> W1104 08:49:29.472478       7 backend_ssl.go:45] Error obtaining X.509 certificate: unexpected error creating SSL Cert: no valid PEM formatted block found

> W1104 08:49:29.472595       7 controller.go:1334] Error getting SSL certificate "myapp-test/myapp-tls": local SSL certificate myapp-test/myapp-tls was not found. Using default certificate

> W1104 08:49:29.472611       7 controller.go:1334] Error getting SSL certificate "myapp-test/myapp-tls": local SSL certificate myapp-test/myapp-tls was not found. Using default certificate

Here is my myapp-ingress.yml

```
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: myapp-test
  namespace: myapp-test
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - test-app.myapp.io
        - test-api.myapp.io
      secretName: myapp-tls
  rules:
    - host: test-app.myapp.io
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: myapp-frontend
                port:
                  number: 80
    - host: test-api.myapp.io
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: myapp-backend-monolith
                port:
                  number: 80
```

Here is my Secret.yml

```
kind: Secret
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: myapp-tls
  namespace: myapp-test
data:
  tls.crt: >-
    BASE64 ENCODED CRT FILE CONTENT
  tls.key: >-
    BASE64 ENCODED KEY FILE CONTENT
type: kubernetes.io/tls
```

I actully tried to create ingresses and/or secrets in every namespaces. But Ingress controller still can't find SSL certificate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

based on below error, appears your cert format is not right.

> no valid PEM formatted block found

Is your original cert in [PEM](https://www.ssl.com/guide/pem-der-crt-and-cer-x-509-encodings-and-conversions/) format? you can decode the cert data in secret and double check, using a command like below (you might need to install `jq` command, or you can copy the tls.crt data manually and decode it with `base64 -d` command):

```
kubectl get secret your-secret-name -n your-namespace -o json | jq '."data"."tls.crt"'| sed 's/"//g'| base64 -d -
```

below is what I did using a self-signed test cert/key file.

```
 kubectl get secret mytest-ssl-secret -o json
```

> ```
> {
>     "apiVersion": "v1",
>     "data": {
>         "tls.crt": "LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBDRVJUSUZJQ0FURS0tLS0tCk1JSUVGVENDQXYyZ0F3SUJBZ0lVWG12blRrcGtqMlhiQkx...tLS0K",
>         "tls.key": "LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBQUklWQVRFIEtFWS0tLS0tCk1JSUV2Z0lCQURBTkJna3Foa2lHOXcwQkFRRUZBQVNDQkt...tLS0K"
>     },
>     "kind": "Secret",
>     "metadata": {
>         "creationTimestamp": "2022-11-05T04:22:12Z",
>         "name": "mytest-ssl-secret",
>         "namespace": "default",
>         "resourceVersion": "2024434",
>         "uid": "d63dce3d-8e5c-478a-be9e-815e59e4bd21"
>     },
>     "type": "kubernetes.io/tls"
> }
> ```

```
kubectl get secret mytest-ssl-secret -o json | jq '."data"."tls.crt"'| sed 's/"//g'| base64 -d -
```

> ```
> -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
> MIIEFTCCAv2gAwIBAgIUXmvnTkpkj2XbBLRJo+mpBfp4mvAwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEL
> BQAwgZkxCzAJBgNVBAYTAkNOMRAwDgYDVQQIDAdKaWFuZ3N1MQ0wCwYDVQQHDARX
> dXhpMRowGAYDVQQKDBFUZXN0IGxpbWl0ZWQgSW5jLjELMAkGA1UECwwCSVQxHDAa
> BgNVBAMME3Rlc3QwMDguZXhhbXBsZS5jb20xIjAgBgkqhkiG9w0BCQEWE3Rlc3Qw
> ...
> XO8B+zyFRP1PZnCAkeUdvh6rpMbVHWvfM0QOG4m736b9FK1VmjTG4do=
> -----END CERTIFICATE-----
> ```